# Angular http $get not retrieving json data on other site

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to get some json content from another website.

it works on local, the distant url in browser gives json data (ex: http://bacly.fr/baclymphp/getTournois.php), but I can't get anything working together.

**Here is a part of my code:**

```
baclyApp.factory("tournois",function($http){
//Provider qui recupère les données de tournois et iscriptions
    // var urlphp="http://localhost/cordova/mbacly/www/php/";
    var urlphp="http://bacly.fr/baclymphp/";


    var tournois={};   
    $http.get(urlphp+"getTournois.php").success(function(data)
     {
         tournois.tournois = data;
     }).error(function(status) {
    alert(status) 
    });
```

The status error returns null.

Any help is welcome!

UPDATE

after having added headers in php files, only chrome still not working. Console provides :

> Refused to connect to 'http://bacly.fr/baclymphp/getTournois.php' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

```
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10352sendReq @ angular.js:10232$get.serverRequest 
@ angular.js:9944processQueue 
@ angular.js:14454(anonymous function)
@ angular.js:14470$get.Scope.$eval 
@ angular.js:15719$get.Scope.$digest 
@ angular.js:15530$get.Scope.$apply 
@ angular.js:15824done 
@ angular.js:10263completeRequest 
@ angular.js:10435requestLoaded 
@ angular.js:10376
angular.js:12221 Error: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Refused to connect to 'http://bacly.fr/baclymphp/getTournois.php' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.
```

Comment: have you enabled CORS?

Comment: Read this: [HTTP Access Control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). In short, what you are doing is a security risk and not allowed by default.

Comment: Probably a cross domain issue. You shud allow origin * on the requested server

Comment: @Brett Whether or not it's a security risk depends entirely on the context of what you're doing.

Comment: @Brad Well yes, that reasoning can be applied to anything. My point is cross-origin requests via ajax are not allowed by default because of obvious security vulnerabilities. I'm not implying you shouldn't or can't do it.

Comment: @Pankaj, no, didnt enabled cors, i ll have a look

Comment: @Brett, i ll have a look too

Comment: i added this on my php code (getTournois.php here)
It works on local with fx (i mean calling distant url), but not on others browsers, nor on my mobile as i want to phonegap my app

Comment: oups i added this and it also works on IE, but still not on chrome/cordova android : 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST');

Comment: i commented         <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
in index.html, and it works now